# How to close the drop down menu again if clicked on the same element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I wrote the following code to get a `drop-down` menu toggled on every click in addition to close any other toggled menus but for some reason I can't get the menu closed after click again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    "use strict";
    $(".dropdown").hide();
    $("#smpg-cat-list li span").click(function() {

      $(".dropdown").hide();

      $("#smpg-cat-list li span").html('<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

      if( $(this).next('.dropdown').css('display') == 'none' ){

         $(this).next('.dropdown').show();

         $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

      }else{

        $(this).next('.dropdown').hide();

        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      }

  });
});
```

So I want the code to:

1. Hide all `.dropdown` classes.
2. Then if clicked on `#smpg-cat-list li span` it should close any
   shown menus if there are.
3. Change the html of hidden elemnts to a plus icon.
4. Then for the current clicked element I check if the next `.dropdown`
   class has a `display = none;`.
5. If true so show this element and change the icon again to minus.
6. If false so hide this element and change the icon to plus

and it shows the element but doesn't hide if clicked again.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="smpg-cat-list">
<li><a href="/web-design/">Web Design</a>
</li>
<li><a href="/robots/">Robots</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="/programming/">Programming</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/programming/php/">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="/programming/c/">C#</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/frameworks/">Frameworks</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/frameworks/laravel/">Laravel</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/data-analysis/">Data Analysis</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="/cms/">CMS</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/cms/wordpress/">WordPress</a></li>
        <li><a href="/cms/joomla/">Joomla</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And no special CSS.

Comment: post both html and css

Comment: Thank you for response, i have added the html and no css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below snipet I after clicking on span , I used `[.find()][1]` , to find the `i` tag and check whether it has a certain class , using `[.hasClass()][1]`
then replace the `fa-plus` with `fa-minus` or make the inverse then show the sibling dropdown .

This should help you :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".dropdown").hide();
  $("#smpg-cat-list li span").click(function() {
    
    $(".dropdown").hide();
   
    var $i  = $(this).find("i");
    console.log($i);
    if ($i.hasClass("fa-plus")) {
      $i.removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
      $(this).next('.dropdown').show();
    } else {
      $i.removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
      $(this).next('.dropdown').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="smpg-cat-list">
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Robots</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Programming</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Frameworks</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Laravel</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Data Analysis</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">CMS</a>
    <span class="toggle" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i need to know why my code doesn't work

Comment: thank you, i accepted the answer but lastly would you please explain why the check i used will always return `none`, and what approach i should use if i want to depend on the css function

Comment: You need to replace your code again, i think you added my code by mistake on the edit